Microsoft Upgrade Assistant Stuck
I am trying to upgrade a class library from ASP.NET 4.8 to .NET Standard 2.0. When I click on Upgrade in VS 2022, I see the output for the Upgrade Assistant below.
Has anyone seen this error? I don't know if it stuck or processing something.
This is the out I am seeing
Found NuGet package Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Mappings v1.0.7
Using extension ApiCatalogExtension from C:\CurrentRelease_Code\baseline\globalpackages\Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.ApiCatalog.Assets\10.0.1
Using API and package mappings from C:\CurrentRelease_Code\baseline\globalpackages\Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Mappings\1.0.7\content\mappings
Using extension LooseAssemblyIndexExtension from 


